# Jquery 1.9.1, CSS & Google Maps: "Display: none" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, css

I'm struggling to get a Google map working on my website. The problem is that the map shows like this:

[image: Google maps on my website (Norwegian language variables)]

Which I understand is a known issue with re-sizing the object after it's div has been shown. (Changed from `display: none;` to `display: block;` that is)

I'm using JQueryUI Tabs and a `display: none;` on the div that encapsulates the tabs.

I did try removing the tabs and displaying all as a block on start, and then do the changes on `window.load` - but it's rather ugly having the watch things move around by itself after you have loaded.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZ2e3/5/) demonstrates how I want it (simplified), although it's flawed as I cannot make it work properly (it's not showing the map at all).

Is there another way to do it - or do I have to find a different kind of layout for my map functionality?

Comment: I have found the only reliable approach is to initialize the map with the canvas at `display:block`, then hide it. If this is done in a `$(function() {...})` structure, then you shouldn't see the map before it's hidden.

Comment: This seems to be the way to do it. I have not made it work properly, but it is forming the way I want it. If you could post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the only reliable approach is to initialize the map with the canvas at `display:block`, then hide it. If this is done in a $(function() {...}) structure, then you shouldn't see the map before it's hidden.

You can also try hiding the canvas initially and initializing the map when it is first needed, after showing the canvas.

Either way, only initialize the map when its canvas is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);  

$("#map_canvas").css("height", $(window).height());
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you manipulate any of the map's outer divs after it has been initialized. So to fix this you must initialize the map after all of its outer divs have been displayed.

So just initialize the map at the very end:

```
$mapsOuterDivs.slideToggle(700);
setTimeout(function(){
    initializeGoogleMap();
},300);
```